# Python docs have misleading explanation of return in finally

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except, finally

I was going through the python docs to improve my core python and I was reading about [errors and exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

In the doc it says

> If a finally clause includes a return statement, the finally clause’s return statement **will execute before, and instead of,** the return statement in a try clause.

It also provides this example below:

```
def bool_return():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        return False

bool_return()
```

Now looking at this example the above statement seems straight and fair enough, but if you modify that example a bit to make it look like this:

```
def bool_return():
    try:
        return print("foo")
    finally:
        return False

bool_return()
```

Now, if you run this you will see that `foo` will be printed and False will be returned. Now the doc says that finally clause's return will execute **before**, and **instead of,** try clause's return statement. If so, then why I can see the foo being printed?

I debugged this snippet with pycharm and it shows that the try clause's return statement is executed first and the string is printed and then it's output which is `None` is returned due to `return` statement, and the return statement in the finally clause will be executed later, which is the last return of the program so the function overrides previous return and `False` is returned.

My question is:

1) Why does doc say finally clause's return statement is executed *before*?

2) Why does doc say finally clause's return statement is executed *instead of* try clause's return statement?

I believe both the statements are the opposite of what happens in reality.

**EDIT:**

After reading @iBug's answer it is clear now that how the `print("foo")` is evaluated but `None` is not returned. Basically, the expression is evaluated first and then `return` happens. Later on `return False` in finally is executed. Which makes clear why we get the output that we did.

Still, I see that the `return False` in finally is executed *after* the `return print("foo")` of try.

Or as per @iBug's comment, `10 RETURN_VALUE` is completely bypassed?

[image]

**EDIT**

This is now resolved in the documentation and it is correct now on what will be returned. However, if you wish to know "how" then read all the comments and answer carefully.

Comment: Sometimes the docs just aren't very well written.

Comment: `return print("foo")` is actually 2 separate steps, first the print function is called, then the return value `None` is assigned to the return statement - __then__ the finally blocks return statement overrides the previous statements value. This is a bit over simplified but you get what I mean

Comment: The return statement in the `try` block is not executed but the expression in it is evaluated.

Comment: @IainShelvington: You can break it into plenty more steps than that (load `print`, load `"foo"`, call function, return value, for starters), but all those steps are part of executing the `return` statement. Return value computation is separate from actually returning the value, but it isn't separate from the overall `return` statement.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I was trying to keep it simple. The return statement is actually just setting the object that will be pushed onto the stack I believe

Comment: Using  `try: return print("foo") finally: return print("bar")` is a bit clearer IMO.  I guess this is just a minor documentation bug, you could submit a PR to modify the wording to fit reality better.

Comment: @wim I guess it so because execution cycle shows that Finally will always execute after try completely done. Python overrides the Return value from the Finally block as other answers suggest. It could be a possible bug in doc.

Comment: The wording is just not good - how can it be both **before** and **instead of**, these are mutually exclusive concepts.

Comment: This is a recent change in the docs, [PR here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15677), and the confusing wording appears to have been taken directly from [this github comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15677#discussion_r323079139).  There were [other problems](https://bugs.python.org/issue38130) introduced from the same PR.

Comment: @wim Agree with you. the documentation seems to be confusing here. Thanks for the PR links

Comment: Would this wording be better: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18324/commits/47e9cfe36a042cde8675d4102b569cd1ebcd6df1?

Comment: @JulienPalard indeed. I was also hoping if there was some explanation included (pretty brief maybe) on how this works, obviously if it in the scope of documentation to do so. I mean it should explicitly mention that when you write `return expression` in try then this expression will be evaluated however not returned.

Comment: @Eternal could you try at giving a wording for this sentence? In the PR maybe? I'm not native english.

Comment: For sure @JulienPalard

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18324#pullrequestreview-352867645 @JulienPalard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
$ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52)
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def bool_return():
...     try:
...         return print("foo")
...     finally:
...         return False
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(bool_return)
  2           0 SETUP_FINALLY            8 (to 10)

  3           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>   10 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

As you can see above, `return False` *does* happen before the `return` statement in the `try` block, but after the to-be-returned value has been computed.

I think the docs probably meant "the very action of returning" by *return statement*, or in other words, it didn't take into account the computation of the return value, which of course happens before it's returned.

---

To observe whether `8 RETURN_VALUE` is executed or not, you can compile CPython interpreter in debug mode and run it in GDB. A step-by-step guide would be too bloated for this answer, so I'll give an outline here (Linux).

- Grab the CPython source code from an official source (python.org website or GitHub)
- Configure the debug build `./configure --with-pydebug` (you may want to give `--prefix=/opt/python3-debug` as well), `make` and `make install`
- Start the debug Python in GDB: `gdb /opt/python3-debug/bin/python3` and (gdb) `r`
- Define the function `bool_return` as usual.
- Locate the string `RETURN_VALUE` in `Python/ceval.c`, take down the line number ([for 3.8.1, it's 1911](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Python/ceval.c#L1911)).
- Hang the Python interpreter by sending `SIGTRAP`, and set a breakpoint at the position from the previous step (`b Python/ceval.c:1911`), and then `c`.
- Watch the breakpoint reached twice, with output like this:

```
(gdb breakpoint info)
False
(gdb breakpoint info)
```

- Observe how the breakpoint is reached once for every statement you enter in the REPL. This is to learn that the second breakpoint in the above step is caused by Python REPL, so only the first breakpoint comes from a `return` statement in the function.

Now that it's clear that only one `return` has been executed in the function, it must be `12 RETURN_VALUE`, so the Python instruction `8 RETURN_VALUE` isn't executed at all.

Comment: I guess the `12 RETURN_VALUE` is the return statement of finally right? Which is after the `8 RETURN_VALUE` which belongs to try clause, isn't it so?

Comment: @Eternal Yes. And the actual execute order is 0→2→4→6→10→12 where 8 is completely bypassed.

Comment: How can we know that? @iBug

Comment: I do not think it is bypassed, but I believe that it is overridden by finally which I think pretty much explains everything.

Comment: @Eternal Whatever you name that isn't important, as long as the meaning remains the same (`8 RETURN_VALUE` isn't executed at all).

Comment: Still not clear, it **bypassed** or **overriden** @iBug

Comment: @Eternal I don't think the wording makes any difference. It's clear that the `print` function is evaluated and the result isn't returned, but the other value from `finally` is returned instead. I have compiled CPython in debug mode and stepped through GDB, and I found that only one `RETURN_VALUE` is executed, so number 8 is clearly **not executed at all**.

Comment: I've updated with more details from running Python interpreter through GDB to support my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: GDB doesn't convince me. Where is the source in the CPython interpreter that causes execution to jump directly from `6` to `10`? Also- you're showing the disassembly for 3.7, in OP (3.8) it looks totally different (see `POP_BLOCK` etc).

Comment: @wim It does not jump from 6 to 10. `RETURN_VALUE` on 8 is for print() function. The `return` in try is not even part of the opcode.

Comment: @Eternal  That's not right.  Change the `return print()` into `return True` and you will still see two `RETURN_VALUE` in the disassembly.

Comment: Which would mean we are still unclear on how that `return` in try is bypassed @wim